# Vuetify v-img doesn't load image with absolute path

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

The problem is simple: I would like to display an image from an absolute path in vuetify with the v-img tag but it is not showing.

I have already tried doing it with `:src="require('path/to/img')"` but then an error comes saying "This dependency was not found"

```
<v-img src="src/assets/project_atv_logo.jpg"
            class="mb-4"
            contain
            height="128"
          ></v-img>
```

The file is stored under src/assets folder.
I am using a mac pc if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
<v-img :src="require('@/assets/project_atv_logo.jpg')"
            class="mb-4"
            contain
            height="128"
          ></v-img>
```

Comment: This dependency was not found:

* @src/assets/project_atv_logo.jpg in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirector
y":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"24ddd4d4-vue-loader-template"}!./node_
modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vuetify-l
oader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-load
er/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=template&id=469af010&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @src/assets/project_atv_logo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

For the Vite environment, the solution is to use `new URL('[path_to_image]', import.meta.url).href`

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75655533)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import logo from '@/assets/logos/banana.svg';
</script>

<template>
    <v-img height="150" :src='logo' />
</template>
```