# Vuetify vite v-img is not found (error 404) when image is stored locally

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am attempting to load an image into a  element but it is only found if the inage is stred at a remote URL, not if it is part of the local file system.

```
<script setup>
var botright_local = './assets/images/bottomright.jpg'
var botright_web = 'https://quilkin.co.uk/img/bottomright.jpg'
</script>   

<template>
  <header>
    <img src="./assets/images/bottomright.jpg" width="125" height="125" />
  </header>
  <main >
    <v-img :src="botright_local"  width="125" height="125"   />
    <v-img :src="botright_web"  width="125" height="125"   />
  </main>
</template>
```

The first image (a standard `<img>` loads OK locally; the second ( a`<v-img>`) gives a 404 error; the third loads OK.

Searches for this error suggest that that I should use `require([path_toimage])` but it appears that `require` is not for use in the vite environment.

Comment: Check my answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75503353/v-img-cant-locate-resource-from-assets-folder/75505467?noredirect=1#comment133226563_75505467

Answer (score 0):

For the Vite environemnt, the solution is to use `new URL('[path_to_image]', import.meta.url).href`

e.g.

```
<script setup>

const botright_vite = new URL('./assets/images/bottomleft.jpg', import.meta.url).href
var botright_web = 'https://quilkin.co.uk/img/bottomright.jpg'
</script>

<template>
  <main >
    <v-img :src="botright_web"  width="125" height="125"   />
    <v-img :src="botright_vite"  width="125" height="125"   />
  </main>
</template>
```

see [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) for more details